# Can I convert a public key to a private key?

Tags: gnupg

I am using [pgp4usb](http://www.gpg4usb.org/) for encryption and decryption. I accidentally deleted it but I still have my old (public) PGP key. Is it possible to import it and use it again as my private key?

The key is following:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- Version: GnuPG v1
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=RnYx
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Comment: short answer is very much: no

Comment: So I lost that key? I cannot use it anymore to encrypt or decrypt files?

Comment: The whole point of a private key is for it to remain private. If there was any to turn a public key into a private key then there wouldn't be a point in having a private key to begin with.

Comment: You should never encrypt with a private key. You can still encrypt with the public key, but that's the equivalent of tossing the bits in the bit bucket, i.e. the ciphertext cannot be reverted into plaintext anymore afterwards.

Comment: The blessing of public-key encryption (aka "asymmetric encryption") is that without the private key, an attacker CAN NOT decrypt your files. The curse is that if you lose the private key, then you can't either. Sorry.

Answer (score 10):

PGP is what is called an "asymmetric cryptosystem."  It is asymmetric because the key used to decrypt data is different than the key used to encrypt data.  In this case, you encrypt data with the *public* key, and then decrypt with the *private* key.  If you lose the private key, data encrypted with the public key is not recoverable.  In the case of a 2048-bit RSA key, chances are you will never be able to recover the key.

Take a look at the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Public key is public -- everybody knows it. If the private key could be rebuilt from the public key, then everybody could do it as well, and the private key would no longer be private.

Fortunately (except for you, in your current predicament), things don't work that way. The public key can be made public *precisely* because doing so does not directly or indirectly reveal the private key. For mathematical details: a public key of type RSA consists in a big integer (the modulus *n*) and another smaller integer (the public exponent *e*). The modulus is the product of two big primes (often denoted *p* and *q*). Knowledge of the private key is equivalent(*) to knowing *p* and *q*. Finding *p* and *q* from *n* is called [integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Integer_factorization), a process which has been studied by mathematicians since at least the New Babylonian Empire (about 2500 years ago) and is, apparently, very hard when the integers become big. Current world record (excluding integers with a special format) is for a [768-bit integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-768). Your RSA key has a 2048-bit modulus, which is completely out of reach of current and foreseeable technology.

Since the private key is lost, anything that was encrypted with the public key can be considered lost data, since it can no longer be decrypted. Next time you will make a safe backup of your private key somewhere else, to avoid this problem. On a general basis, keys used for *encryption* must be backupped, since their loss implies the loss of everything that was encrypted with them; on the other hand, keys for for *signatures* should not be backupped, since their "proving value" relies on the private key being as private as can be achieved.

<sup>(*) There are subtleties in this assertion but they don't really matter here.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you have a public PGP key but you deleted your private key.  Recomputing your private key is equivalent to breaking the encryption ... in this case it seems to be 2048-bit encryption, which is not going to be easy to break.

Comment: "not going to be easy to break" is quite an understatement here.

Comment: ... by several orders of magnitude...

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not be able to recover a lost private key.

The point of encryption is to *prevent* decryption without the secret used (a passphrase, private key, ...). If you'd be able to decrypt files *without* the private key with any reasonable amount of computation effort, encryption would've been useless from the start.

Answer (score 1):

It's practically impossible to convert a public key to a private key. If we see ECC equation `K = k*G` here K is public key and G is point of ECC curve and k is private key. It can easily possible to create public key from k and G but not possible to retrive k from K,G. Why?

Because of discrete logarithmic problem that's why this is can be said it's a one direction equation. If you want to know more about that read this [documentation](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/04keys-addresses.asciidoc)